# Deploy Django project on Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have developed one example project in django1.4 & python 2.7, I want to deploy it on google app engine,
but how to configure my project as per App Engine we didn't get.

We have a site running on google app engine, but it is including with all html,js.

How do we configure a database on google app engine to deploy our django project?

Comment: What kind of database?

Comment: in my app i am using models.py, that is with MYSQL

Comment: You'll have to switch to a database supported by the App Engine environment.  I have not done this so can't advise... but Google provides an example of a cloud sql app here:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/training/cloud-sql/

Comment: There might also be a module for django to use either google's cloud sql or the old google database, which was a giant key/value store.  But I've never done this so maybe someone else will drop by and help...

Comment: This also looks interesting: http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine

Comment: I am working on Windows Environment, django-norel is in Linux environment it seems. I tried but i didn't get

Answer (score 3):

Possibly the best option is to use Django Non-Rel. It's the only way (that I know of) to use the Django ORM (the django database interface) on Google App Engine without using Google's costly cloud SQL service.  To do this, you'll need to use a customized version of Django and import several more libraries.  It's a small project to get it up and running, but it's worth the effort.  More information can be found on this website:

http://django-nonrel.org/

Note, that even though django-nonrel allows you to use the Django database interface, it will **not** allow you to use certain SQL features, such as joins. If you need joins, then your best option would be to use Google App Engine + Google Cloud SQL. [Documentation for that is here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django).

Regarding the comments:

- Yes, it can run on windows, I run it on Windows.
- Also, the site allbuttonspressed.com is old and out of date, use the
  one above for information.